# Как в VBA отправить файл на поту в определённом формате?

Tags: vba

Есть такой скрипт

```
Sub SendWorkbook()
    ActiveWorkbook.SendMail Recipients:="KAZ.19.01.1999@yandex.ru", Subject:="Лови файлик"
End Sub

Sub SendSheet()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Таблица").Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SendMail Recipients:="KAZ.19.01.1999@yandex.ru", Subject:="Лови файлик"
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

А как можно изменить формат отправляемого файла на csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед отпрвкой создайте файл с нужным расширением:

```
 With ActiveWorkbook
    sPath = .Path ' путь к активной книге

    .SaveAs Filename:=sPath & "\" & "111.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS 
    ........
```